# SwiftUI .navigationBarItems .sheet crashing after adding the presentationMode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I have created a ContentView() page that shows the main content of the app. Before adding the `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` and the function concerning the presentationMode, the sheet view of the trailing part was functioning without any problems. Now the home button (leading) works well and allows me to return to the menu page of the app but clicking the other button (trailing) crashes the app immediately. The weird thing is that the ContentView() itself is functioning without any problems in the preview mode but crashes the simulator. I have tried many things but couldn't find the right way to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

This is the part from the ContentView():

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var isAddPresented = false
@State var isActive : Bool = false
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
func goBack(){

        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

    }
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text("")
                        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                        .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                                Button(action: goBack) {
                                                Image("Home") },trailing:
                                                
                                                Button(action: {
                                                self.isAddPresented = true
                                                }) {
                                                Image("Rules_Click")
                                    
                                                            }).padding()
                                                }.sheet(isPresented: $isAddPresented,
                                                onDismiss: { self.isAddPresented = false })
                {RulesView()}.padding(.bottom, 100.0)
            }
    }
```

and this is the part from the HomeView():

```
HStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()){
                Image("NormalCards")
                    .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)     
            }
                
        }
```

And here is the RulesView part:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RulesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("Rules")
            .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    }
}

struct Rules_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RulesView()
    }
}
```

Edit:

Changing the .navigationBarItems to toolbar didn't change anything.

```
                            .toolbar{
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        goBack()
                                    }, label: {
                                        Image("Home")
                                    })
                                }
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.isAddPresented = true
                                    }, label: {
                                        Image("Rules_Click")
                                    }).sheet(isPresented: $isAddPresented, onDismiss: { self.isAddPresented = false }) {RulesView()}
                                }
                        }
```

Edit Nr.2 :

Here using Text("ExampleText") instead of ZStack works just fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var isAddPresented = false
    
    func goBack(){
        dismiss() // reset to home view
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
                ZStack(alignment:.center) {
                                ForEach(Card.data) { card in
                                    CardView(card: card)
                                }
                            }
        
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    goBack()
                }, label: {
                    Image("Home")
                })
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isAddPresented = true
                }, label: {
                    Image("Rules_Click")
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isAddPresented) {
            RulesView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can find the CardView() information regarding the ZStack:

```
struct CardView: View {
    @State var card: Card
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(card.imageName)
        }
        //.background(brownish)
        .offset(x: card.x, y: card.y)
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: card.deg))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
        
                .onChanged { value in
                    withAnimation(.default){
                        card.x = value.translation.width
                        card.y = value.translation.height
                        card.deg = 7*(value.translation.width > 0 ? 1 : -1)
                    }
                    
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 50, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0)) {
                        switch value.translation.width {
                            case 0...100:
                                card.x = 0; card.deg = 0; card.y = 0
                            case let x where x > 100:
                                card.x = 500; card.deg = 12
                            case (-100)...(-1):
                                card.x = 0; card.deg = 0; card.y = 0;
                            case let x where x < -100:
                                card.x = -500; card.deg = -12
                            default: card.x = 0; card.y = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have in RulesView? Clicking the trailing nav button crashes the app, and this may be related to RulesView. Also you should use ".toolbar" for navigation bar items since ".navigationBarItems" is deprecated.

Comment: RulesView only has an image in it. I will try to use the .toolbar from now on thanks for the advice!

Comment: did that already solve your issue?

Comment: unfortunately not I have recently uploaded the version with .toolbar you can check it :)

Comment: This is probably caused by the `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` Is there any other way to return to the home view with a custom toolbar button?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you should pull the `.sheet` out of the `.toolbar`.
Secondly each modal view has its own `dismiss`, so maybe the two (NavigationLink and Sheet) interfere.
Lastly you can use `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` instead of `.presentationMode` (it is basically the same thing, just shorter)

I reordered a little and came to this, which works for me:

```
struct HomeView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink {
                    ContentView()
                } label: {
                    Text("NormalCards")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var isAddPresented = false
    
    func goBack(){
        dismiss() // reset to home view
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Example Text")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    goBack()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Home")
                })
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.isAddPresented = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("Rules")
                })
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isAddPresented) {
            RulesView()
        }
    }
}

struct RulesView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Here are the rules")

                .toolbar {
                    Button("Close") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! With your current version it is working just fine. But if I add a ZStack instead of the `Text("Example Text")` it crashes again. I will update the original question with the mentioned ZStack information and appreciate your help :)

Comment: Works fine with me also with ZStack . Did you try to run it on a real device?

Comment: I will try and update you. Btw I have just updated the question you can view the ZStack code and the CardView() code that I have used in my application.

Comment: I have tried to run it on my real device and the app is still immediately crashing after pressing the button regarding sheet...

Comment: what is `ForEach(Card.data)` - where and how do you declare it? that looks strange as `Card` seems to be the type for your cards ... maybe the issue is there. Try to run your foreach card deck in a ZStack without anything else.

Comment: without the .toolbar, the ZStack and the ‘ForEach(Card.data)’ are running flawlessly.